# android - facebook sample is not working

Tags: android, facebook

I am newbie to Facebook integration to android apps. I am trying to run the app which is  from [Facebook getting started.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/) But it is not working. I am not getting the user name. Why it is not working? Can anyone help me.

I got the following one for the session variable.

`session: {Session state:OPENING, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[]}, appId:360610310722942}`

`session opened: false`

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // start Facebook Login
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        // callback when session changes state
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            final TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
            System.out.println("session: " + session);
            System.out.println("session opened: " + session.isOpened());
            if (session.isOpened()) {

                // make request to the /me API
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                        new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                            // callback after Graph API response with user
                            // object
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                    Response response) {

                                if (user != null) {

                                    welcome.setText("Hello "
                                            + user.getName() + "!");
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    System.out.println("onActivityResult");
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
            resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue and I just fix this. 
The cause is my project is in Sandbox mode. Disable sandbox mode and the app works fine
[image]

Comment: In Which case Sandbox Mode is enabled?

Comment: Enabled is Enabled. Disabled is Disable :| Screenshot above is disabled sandbox mode.